# How to read unicode from text file and write respective string into exel file by using Python

Tags: python, unicode

I have a file which contains Unicode characters of Japanese language in a file and I would like to read the Unicode from the file and write the respective non-Unicode character (string) into some another file.

The Unicode in the file is like this:

```
\u6C0F\u540D 
\u7BA1\u7406\u8005\u540D
\u4F4F\u6240
\u96FB\u8A71\u756A\u53F7
\u30E1\u30FC\u30EB\u30A2\u30C9\u30EC\u30B9
```

Actually, I want to generate an Excel file from this unicode, which consists of the non-Unicode characters of the mentioned unicode.

Comment: What does your code look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a file called `japanese.txt` with the following contents:

```
\u6C0F\u540D 
\u7BA1\u7406\u8005\u540D
\u4F4F\u6240
\u96FB\u8A71\u756A\u53F7
\u30E1\u30FC\u30EB\u30A2\u30C9\u30EC\u30B9
```

You could add it to an Excel file with `openpyxl`, using the following code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from openpyxl import Workbook
import codecs

with codecs.open('japanese.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8') as file:
    s = file.read()

s = s.decode('unicode-escape')

wb = Workbook()

ws = wb.active

ws['A1'] = 42

ws.append([1, 2, 3])

import datetime
ws['A2'] = s

wb.save("sample.xlsx")
```

Comment: Tons of Thanks for the solution..I have been scratching my head from one day for the solution..Thanks a lot..

Answer (score 0):

It appears that there is a package that can work for you called [unidecode](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode).  It would do this very easily.  For instance:

```
>>> from unidecode import unidecode
>>> print(unidecode(u"\u6C0F\u540D"))
Shi Ming
```